# Is it recommended to use kustomize after helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kustomize

Sometimes when I use helm charts, not all things I want to modify are usable with the given values. Is it practical to use kustomize to modify the rendered helm chart?
So like this:
chart -> helm template -> kustomize -> kubectl deploy

Comment: This is an opinionated question. But I would recommend `kustomize`, it is a newer tool and it is closer to Kubernetes config management vision.

Comment: The Kustomize Background white paper is a good read, it also compares to Helm: https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/architecture/declarative-application-management.md

Comment: Yes, doing kustomize over result of helm template is a common pattern - Google for kustomize over helm.

Comment: The whitepaper that @Jonas linked to has since been moved here: https://github.com/kubernetes/design-proposals-archive/blob/main/architecture/declarative-application-management.md

Comment: From Helm 3.1+ onwards we can use helm's post rendering mechanism to call tools like kustomize https://helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#post-rendering

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We do use it sometimes. You can use Helm directly in Kustomize with the helmCharts plugin. In my example, `values-prod.yaml` has to be in the same directory as the `kustomization.yaml`. `namespace: custom-metallb` will override `namespace: metallb` for example.

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: custom-metallb

helmCharts:
- name: metallb
  namespace: metallb
  releasename: metallb
  repo: https://metallb.github.io/metallb
  version:  0.10.2
  ValuesFile: values-prod.yaml
```

To be honest, the documentation is not that great, but you can find the arguments here:
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/api/types/helmchartargs.go

Documentation from kustomize:
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/chart.md

Comment: How am I JUST NOW LEARNING that this exists?